# How to break out of while loop using a blank line?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop

I have to create a program which requests the user to input file names (one per line). Since I don't know how many file names the user might enter, I thought that the while loop would be suffice enough to store the file names within an array list. Each time the user enters a file name within the while loop, it stores it within the array list. But I am having trouble breaking out of the while loop when the user enters a blank line i.e double returns when they are done entering the file names.

Comment: What is the trouble?  Are you using `break` to break out of the loop?  Code would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Set up an if statement checking if the value of the user input is ""

Comment: Sorry dont have a code atm, just trying to figure out how to break out of a while loop when the user enters a blank line. Such as: while(filenames.hasNext) {//code}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will take a line of input from the user and print it back out until the user enters an empty line. you can change the printing to whatever logic you need.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
while ((input = s.nextLine()).length() > 0)
{
  System.out.println(input);
}
```